# Microsoft graph webhook subscription for OneNote changes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

Can I use MS graph webhook subscription to work with OneNote notebook changes ?

To serve the purpose served by OneNote subscription [described at](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-sync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Currently, you wont be able to use Microsoft Graph webhooks to subscribe for the OneNote Notebook Notification.
Currently OneNote Webhooks only support Microsoft Account (O365 use cases are not supported for OneNote webhooks).

Although, if you want to subscribe for OneNote webhooks, contact @Onenotedev (on twitter) or you can reach out to me. I can provide you with further details.

After your application is set up on OneNote side to receive notification. You will receive notification from OneNote on using either Graph OneNote Api endpoint or OneNote Api endpoint.

Comment: Does this means for work/school account webhooks(enterprise account) are not supported. If I have microsoft account(consumer account) then only I can get notification using webhooks for any changes. 

Can you please share the details on how to proceed with webhooks. My email id is poojadhannawat@gmail.com.

Thanks in advance